# How do i extract the numbers from this input format?

Tags: c, input

i need to "scan" exactly like the line i highlighted. how do i extract the numbers? Im at the start of the course so dont post overcomplicated solution i might not have studied yet.

Enter (House-cost, down-payment, savings, savings-annual-rate, mortgage-annual-rate,
salary, fraction-saving, annual-raise, house-rent):

**(600000, 0.15, 50000, 0.02, 0.03, 10000, 0.3, 0.03, 2000)**

*C LANGUAGE.*

Comment: Weclome, please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to show what you have tried so far. That is, an attempt to input and scan the data, and print the values extracted.

Comment: @WeatherVane Only wrote the printf line. no idea how to scan this.

Comment: You might explore the `fgets` and the `sscanf` functions.

Comment: @noornapso "Only wrote the printf line" --> post that code.

Answer (score 1):

> how do i extract the numbers?

The *easy* approach is to read the line with `fgets()` and then parse with `sscanf()` and `"%n"` to record the offset of the scanning, if it got that far.

Use a format that is tolerant of white-space near the `(,)` separators.
`"%lf"` already consumes leading white-space.

```
  #define EXPECTED_SIZE 100
  char buffer[EXPECTED_SIZE * 2];  // Be generous in buffer size

  // Was a line successfully read?
  if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) {

    // Example code simplified to 3 variables
    double House_cost, down_payment, savings;
    int n = 0;
    sscanf(buffer, " (%lf ,%lf ,%lf ) %n",
        &House_cost, &down_payment, &savings, &n);
    // Did scanning reach the %n and was that the end of the line?
    if (n > 0 && buffer[n] == '\0') {
      Success();
    } else {
      Failed();
    }
  }
```

A *good* parser is ready to detect bad input.  Do not assume input is well formatted.

Answer (score 0):

There are a set of C ANSI Standard library functions to convert character data to numeric data.  These are in the stdlib.h header file and are atoi(), atof(), atol(), atoll().  These functions convert alpha to integer, floating point double, long integer and long long integer data types.

If not familiar with C language, reference online documentation available for the GNU C/C++ compiler...[GNU C Run-Time Library Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/pdf/libc.pdf)

[GNU C Compiler and Language Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.pdf)